# How to read command line(argv) in a form of application of C++ Builder?

Tags: c++, c++builder

Using **C++** with **Borland**, I tried to read command line `argv`

I need in the form, when user click one button it will read the value of command line `argv`.
but the problem is, I cannot find `void main(int argc, char ** argv)`.

I have tried that in debug, I put `argv` or in the **cpp** file of form I put `LPSTR`, but it doesn't work.

I found that there is only **WinMain**, what is more, in the cpp file of form, there is no "WinMain", may I ask how to get it ?

Comment: One reason that you cannot find `void main` is that it's non-standard and thus highly unlikely to be generated by any tool except Microsoft's (where it presumably is done for the purpose of vendor lock-in). Both the C and C++ standards require `main` to have result type `int`.

Answer (score 4):

Typically in a C++ Builder GUI project, you do not have a standard C++ `main()` function. Whilst you can use the Win32 `GetCommandLine` API function, you still have to parse the command line into separate arguments. So the runtime offers helper functions to read command line arguments, like [`System::ParamStr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ParamStr), [`System::Sysutils::FindCmdLineSwitch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FindCmdLineSwitch), etc.

Comment: `ParamStr()` is not limited to just GUI projects.

Comment: @Remy I did not say that was so

Comment: the wording of your answer suggests that `ParamStr()` can only be called in a GUI project, and that is simply not true.

Comment: @Remy the wording does not suggest that

Comment: It did before you just re-wrote it :)

Comment: @Remy No it did not imply that. But I think it is clearer now. So thank you for prompting me.

Comment: Note that System::ParamStr() does not work with OS X applications.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`GetCommandLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in conjunction with [`CommandLineToArgvW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Note that the latter is only available in wide character version.

Alternatively you can replace `WinMain` with a standard `main`, and change the build options to use standard `main`, if that's supported (it is with Visual C++ and with GNU g++). Or if the compiler supports this language extension you can use the wide character `wmain`. A problem with the standard `main` is that the arguments are encoded as Windows ANSI, which among other shortcomings means that they cannot represent all valid Windows filenames, while the arguments of `wmain`, and the arguments retrieved byu `CommandLineToArgvW`, can.

---

A final alternative is to parse the command line that you get as fourth argument of `WinMain`. However, that has no advantages. `WinMain` is a residual from the 16-bit Windows days, it has never had a technical purpose, and is best removed if possible.

---

All the above solutions work with not just Borland C++ Builder but with any Windows C++ compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You can either:

1. use the RTL's [`ParamCount()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.ParamCount) and [`ParamStr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.ParamStr) functions in `System.hpp`.
2. use the C runtime's global [`_argc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Argc) and [`_argv`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Argv,_wargv) variables in `stdlib.h`.
3. Use the Win32 API's [`GetCommandLineW()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156.aspx) and [`CommandLineToArgvW()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391.aspx) functions in `windows.h` and `shellapi.h`, respectively.

As for `WinMain()`, it is located in your project's main .cpp file, which is different than the .cpp file that your Form is implemented in.  In the Project Manager, right-click on your .exe file and choose `View Source`. Or simply open the `<ProjectName>.cpp` file directly.

Comment: Are _argc and _argv standard, or vendor specific?

Comment: Vendor-specific, just like any other underscore-prefixed identifier is. But Borland is not the only vendor that implements these particular identifers. QNXCS Neutrino, Blackberry 10 (which is based on QNX), and TurboC also do, just to name a few.  But the OP is using C++Builder, which has them, so I mentioned them.